# Invalid syntax error in urls.py

Tags: python

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html')),
    url(r'^resturants/$', resturant_ListView.as_view(),
    url(r'^resturants/punjabi/$', punjabiresturant_ListView.as_view(),
    url(r'^resturants/thai/$', thairesturant_ListView.as_view(),
    url(r'^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html')),

url(r'^contact/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact.html')),#ERROR
    ]
```

Getting error in urls.py .Getting error in urls.py .Getting error in urls.py

Comment: You are missing at least three closing parentheses.  If your editor doesn't highlight matching parentheses when you select one, get a better editor.

Answer (score -1):

There is a comma at the end of the line. Remove it

```
url(r'^contact/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact.html')),#ERROR
```

Comment: A trailing comma in a Python list is not any sort of problem.